# How to hide domain name from html5 location services?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, geolocation

We have a web booking widget hosted on saytaxi.com. Widget uses browser location services to determine your location, but you need to approve the request in browser - you will see a popup saying "Saytaxi.com is requesting to share your location".
Problem is we distribute this widget via iframe, but it always requests to share location from the domain where it is located - saytaxi.com

See for example - http://saytaxicr.com

Is there a way to request location from the domain where the iframe is stored?

Comment: you can use a script instead of an iframe, and have the script add the iframe, and it can ask for perms from the expected domain

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have the embedding site include your script and then pass the data using [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) (or by embedding it in the URL you put in the iframe's src).

Comment: but then you need script on top anyway, so why not just do one entry point (a script)?